# Error in passing variable value for editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, razor

In the index, I have the following link for the object to be edited:

```
<div class="editor-field">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = thing.Id })</div>
```

At my controller, I have the following method signature:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Thing thing)
```

But This is not called, instead, an error is displayed which specifies null value is passed.
The link contains the required ID value of the object.
Do I need to change the signature of Edit method in the controller ?

Update:
The example fails even with the changes with the error message as

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId)'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I need to change the signature of Edit method in the controller ?

Yes, since you are passing only an `id` parameter in your `Html.ActionLink` you can't expect to get something more in your `Edit` action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    Thing thing = ... go and fetch the thing from the id
    ...
}
```